# How to receive and send messages when the deviceis in the middle of a connection?

Tags: insert, queue, corruption, integrity

A device establishes and sends messages to B device in plain text (without any encryption). C device is in the middle of the communication and wants to insert extra messages in the A to B communication and as well, it wants to corrupt some messages of the communication. The network is the following one:

> A---->(C)---->B

As the C device is not the destination and it has to be "invisible" to A and B. How it could be implemented? The reception (read) and sending (write) of the messages has to be done at low level in terms of inserting the message (packet with every header) in the queue? As C device is not the destination, the implementation cannot be done by sockets in order to receive and send information? Which language woulb de the suitable for this implementation?

Comment: "How it could be implemented?" Depends a lot on the network details. Can you provide any more information about the network setup, technologies used, etc?

Comment: The question is more about how could the device C "pick" the messages sent by A to B. It could be done by sockets knowing that it is the middle of the communication? Or the best way would be to manage queues in low level?